# readline command in R is not executing further programming lines

Tags: r, readline

I am fairly new in R programming and want to grab keyboard entry to execute further programming codes. As the code as given here is executed, everything works all good but when the exit is entered the program is terminated and it didn't print `y` and `z`.

Could you please advise me how to use `readline` command in loop and execute other program lines after that loop?

```
n=1
a=1
y=c()
z=c()
x=""

while(x!="exit"){

      x<-readline("Enter your name ")
      library(stringr)

      if(x!="exit" & str_detect(x,"N")){

           y[n]=x
           n=n+1

          }else{ 

                z[a]=x
                a=a+1

               }


}

print(y)
print(z)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am just running this code from the terminal and the problem is different than the link which you have attached. In my code after typing the exit, the programme is getting terminated and not executing the lines after the {} brackets, which is this case print(y) and print(z). cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works. I have copied it in a `foo.R` file as so :

```
# in "foo.R"
n = 1
a = 1
y = character()
z = character()
x = ""
library(stringr)
while (x!="exit") {
    x <- readline("Enter your name\n")
    if (x!="exit" & str_detect(x,"N")) {
        y[n] = x
        n = n+1
    } else {
        z[a] = x
        a = a+1
    }
}
print(y)
print(z)
```

And then, from my R console (with the proper working directory), I can run :

```
source("foo.R")
# Enter your name
# Bob
# Enter your name
# Nate
# Enter your name
# exit
# [1] "Nate"
# [1] "Bob"  "exit"
```

and it seems to work just fine.

Comment: @ Vongo, thanks very much. I tried to run the same program from R terminal than it is working all good as you have noticed, but while I am running the same program in RStudio it is giving me trouble as I have described earlier. Do you know what is the problem??